# Accessing folder in console application

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm trying to write a function to read csv contents into a datatable.
I'm getting an exception about the file path and wondering what it is that I'm doing wrong.
All I did was create the console app and create a folder in the project called 'Data'.

```
public DataTable ReadCSV(string filename)
{
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM " + filename;
        string path = "Data\\";
        string connstring = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path + filename + ";" + "Extended Properties='text;FMT=Delimited(;);HDR=YES'";
        OleDbConnection conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connstring);
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, conn);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            da.Fill(dt);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(filename + "not found");
        }

        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
        return dt;
    }

}
```

My connection string in the Text visualizer when I run in debug mode:

Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Data\Positions.csv;Extended Properties='text;FMT=Delimited(;);HDR=YES'

I'm getting an exception

base {System.Data.Common.DbException} = {"'Data\Positions.csv' is not a valid path.  Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides."}

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I have limited experience doing console apps so it's probably some formatting mistake that I've made.  Thanks

Comment: Are you clear on what folder your console app is running in?  I'd assume the bin\debug folder if you are still developing it.  Is there really a bin\debug\data folder with the Positions.csv file in it?

Comment: Russell, didn't realize the bin/debug problem when running a console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> and create a folder in the project called 'Data'.

That doesn't work.  Your program is running in the bin\Debug subdirectory of your project.  It doesn't have a Data subdirectory.  You'd have to use `..\..\Data\Positions.csv` to find that file.

Well, that would solve your problem right now but it isn't going to be useful once you copy your program to another machine.  There won't be a `..\..\Data` directory there.  Think about ways that your user is going to tell you where the .csv file is located.  A GUI with OpenFileDialog is the friendly way but not very compatible with a console app.  The standard way for that is to pass command line arguments.  Environment.CommandLine.  Not very compatible with the typical user.  You'll have to weigh these options by yourself.